# jQuery Sticky Navigation Center during scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

How can i set the width of the Navigation during scrolling. The Navigation fits 100% width during scrolling. If i set the width to 500px than its left:0 positioned. At left i cant set auto center the Navigation.

http://jsfiddle.net/aY8a7/

```
$(function() {

    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;

    var sticky_navigation = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });
        } else {
            $('#navigation_menu').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
        }  
    };

    sticky_navigation();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
         sticky_navigation();
    });

});
```

Comment: your question is not clear . can you explain more what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/aY8a7/1/

```
$(function() {

    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;

    var sticky_navigation = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top
        var $ul = $('#sticky_navigation ul').width()+'px';

        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });
            $('#sticky_navigation ul').css({'width':$ul, 'display':'block', 'text-align':'center'});
        } else {
            $('#navigation_menu').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
        }  
    };

    sticky_navigation();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
         sticky_navigation();
    });

});
```